# Search for an object in rails by an array and create objects if not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call the `ActiveRecord` method `where` with an array for a column. If the each item on the array doesn't exist, create the object. The closest method I found for this is `first_or_create` but this seems to be called only once, not for each time the record doesn't exist. Below is my example code-

```
hashtag_list = params[:message][:hashtag_primary]
@hashtags = Hashtag.where({:name => hashtag_list}).first_or_create do |hashtag|
   hashtag.creator = current_user.id
end
```

Rails version- 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of `where` + `first_or_create` method. Basically `where(field: array)` produces an SQL to find all records where `field` matches **any** item in the `array`. Than you have `first_or_create` method which takes the first record from results or creates a new one with escaped `array` value assigned to a `field` (so something like `field: "[\"foo\", \"bar\"]"` when used as `where(field: %w(foo bar))`.

If you want to create records for each hashtag from your list, you should iterate over it:

```
if @hashtag = Hashtag.where({:name => hashtag_list}).first
  # do something if found the first one
else
  hashtag_list.each do |hashtag|
    # create an object
  end
end
```

If you want to create missing hashtags even if the record is found, you can extract this to a private helper method with missing tags as the argument and re-write code as:

```
if @hashtags = Hashtag.where({:name => hashtag_list})
  # do something if found
end

create_missing_hashtags(hashtag_list - @hashtags.pluck(:name))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a direct method, only a workaround

```
existing_tags =  Hashtag.where({:name => hashtag_list}).pluck(:name)
not_existing_tags =  hashtag_list - existing_tags
@hashtags =  Hashtag.where({:name => existing_tags}).all 
not_existing_tags.each do |tag|
   @hashtags << Hashtag.new name: tag
end

@hashtags.each do |hashtag|
   hashtag.creator = current_user.id
end
```